# Using twilio number to send to the same twilio number

Tags: twilio

I am trying to send a message using my owned twilio number to the same number. However I am not receiving the text at all.The response I get is from this website 
https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/reply/

Thanks for the message. Configure your number's SMS URL to change this message.Reply HELP for help.Reply STOP to unsubscribe.Msg&Data rates may apply.

Can anyone assist on how to send the message?

I cant do it using my number because I dont stay in the states,and it cost money to send an international message because I owned a US number from twilio.

Comment: Could you set up a different twilio number to use for testing? this would probably be cleaner than using the same number.

Comment: i did.. but its receiving nothing..

Comment: Seems more suited to superuser.SE as there is no code involved in this question.

Comment: With your twilio trial you need to add the destination number (in this case the other twilio number) in the 'verified caller id' page and set a destination url to send the received message to. What do you mean by 'its receiving nothing'? How are you checking this?

Comment: Also 'verified caller id' should be set on the number that you are receiving on too.

Comment: Twilio employee here. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish and perhaps include some of your code? You can certainly send messages between Twilio numbers (even between the same one) but the use cases for that are somewhat specialized and I imagine you're trying to accomplish something else.

Answer (score 1):

When you send any message to your Twilio number, Twilio looks at your numbers here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming and requests the Messaging URL configured in that number's settings. By default it is that demo message.

If you just want to send an SMS message to any phone, use the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) (replace the bits in ALL_CAPS):

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages \
-d 'To=+1PHONE_NUMBER' -d 'From=+1YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER' -d 'Body=Hello world!' \
-u 'YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'
```

If I missed the mark, please send a little more info about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different issues here. The first has been addressed by liquidki, where you need to configure the inbound webhook number in the Twilio console.

The other issue is the actual question, which unfortunately is not possible, per Twilio documentation (at least as of 9.16.20): https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21211

> Invalid 'To' Phone Number
>
> . . .
>
> This error will also occur if you attempt to place a call or send a
> message from a Twilio phone number to itself (i.e. putting the same
> Twilio number in the To and From parameters).